# Text manipulation in next line after replace-match

Tags: elisp, motion

I have some function like this:

```
(defun some-function ()
  (interactive)
  (while (re-search-forward "^(def" nil t)
    (replace-match "hello")
    ;; -- Go to next line and do something here
    ))
```

Now once the regexp matches on and replaces the word, I want to go to the next line and do some text manipulation in the second line (like inserting some characters at the start of the line). How would I do that ?

Comment: `(forward-line 1)`?

Comment: @kaushalmodi Facepalm! Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(forward-line 1)` will take the point to the next line.

You can learn more about that and other motion commands from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Lines.html).